# <Maven>How to add class files as dependency (not jar) in maven project?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have two modules, A and B, they are under the same parent. Now A is requiring for B as dependency. I can't just use `jar` as dependency type because module B is using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, so I was wondering how can I set A's pom configuration to make A depend on B's compiled classes not `jar`?

```
- root
  - A
    - src         # module A's source code
    - target
      - classes   # module A's compiled classes
      - A.jar     # module A's compiled jar output
    - pom.xml     # module A's mvn config
  - B
    - src         # module B's source code
    - target
      - classes   # module B's compiled classes, HOW CAN I IMPORT THESE TO A?
      - B.jar     # module B's mvn config
    - pom.xml     # module B's mvn config
  - pom.xml       # parent mvn config
```

**parent mvn config**

```
...
<modules>
  <module>A</module>
  <module>B</module>
</modules>
...
```

**module A mvn config**

```
...
<parent>
  <!- pointed to parent ->
</parent>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <scope>??????????????</scope>   # WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?
    <type>???????????????</type>    # WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?
  </dependency>
<dependencies>
...
```

Comment: You need B's classes at runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: When A depends on the classes of some other module, it necessarily depends on the *jar*. You cannot depend on parts of a module or just the classes.

So let me sketch a solution:

1. If B is of `<packaging>jar</packaging>` (standard, also true if no packaging is given), then you can just use it as dependency. You do not need a scope or type entry.
2. If B is of some other packaging (including spring-defined packaging types, which I am no expert of), then you should *not* define a dependency from A on B. Instead, you define a third module C, which includes the classes that are used from A and from B and let both of them have a dependency on C.

Don't try to construct dependencies to non-jars. If you need classes, define a module with these classes and use it when the classes are needed.

Comment: Thank you. Your second solution makes sense. I've tested it!

Answer (score -2):

Here is good information about maven dependency scope and type.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

This should work fine for you. (Not tested)

```
<scope>compile</scope>
<type>jar</type>
```

Comment: from the question *make A depend on B's compiled classes not jar*.  How would your solution satisfy this?

Comment: That's why I have mentioned compile scope. If I provide scope as runtime, then it will be on jar.

Comment: Could you test your code and confirm if A doesn't use B's jar there.

Comment: You should also mention that this is usually not put into the pom file cause it's the default so in other words in can be omitted. (for explanation purposes it's fine)...

Comment: Hi @nagendra547, thank you for your answer. I've tested your solution but it's not working. As I've mentioned I can't use `<type>jar</type>`, because B's output jar has [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html), if I depend on this jar, there will be `*** from B doesn't exist` error when packaging A module.

Comment: @Kim Have you read my answer? If B does not produce a usual jar, you _cannot_ use classes from B in A. Construct an additional module with the shared classes.