# Add class files to maven as a dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am trying to use maven in an old Java Applets project using eclipse. The original project has as dependency class files from another project (Not jar). How could I manage this with maven? I don't know if it is possible for maven to point to class files instead to a jar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<Maven>How to add class files as dependency (not jar) in maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011442/mavenhow-to-add-class-files-as-dependency-not-jar-in-maven-project)

Comment: Note that Applets are not supported any more.

Comment: I just want Maven in order to avoid the jar-hell management